# How to pass query string parameters in URL in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to replicate this same URL`http://localhost:1555/api/Data/GetPendingLevelTwo?levelId=2` in Django it takes a query parameter.
Thought, I'm using the function based view for my whole project and no Serializers. All I just fetch from database and show it in front end.

This is what I have tried

views.py:

```
 def GetPendingLevelTwo(request, levelId):
     if request.method == 'GET':
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[usp_getLevelTwo] @lvlOneId=%s,', (levelId))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        print('PendingLevelOne', result_set)
        data = []
        for i in range(len(result_set)):
            data.append({
                'L1Id': result_set[i][0],
                'Level1':result_set[i][1]
            })
        return Response(data)
```

urls.py:

Here, I want to pass the `?` instead of `/`

```
 path('Data/GetPendingLevelTwo/<int:levelId>', GetPendingLevelTwo, name='GetPendingLevelTwo'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `<int:levelId>` part from the URL pattern.

```
path('Data/GetPendingLevelTwo/', GetPendingLevelTwo, name='GetPendingLevelTwo'),
```

And then you can capture the query paramter in FBV using `request.GET.get('parameter_name')`

```
def get_pending_level_two(request):
    level_id = request.GET.get('levelId', None)
    if level_id:
        print("level_id is present in the Query param")
    else:
        print("level_id is missing")
```

Note: This solution is not tested.

Comment: without passing a parameter in the URL how does the method get the parameter all it just take the parameter from the URL. However, still it doesn't able to get the URL in such format. have tried ur solution as well